# Qt - How to make QTextBrowser resize to contents (vertical layout)

Tags: html, qt, resize

I have a QTextBrowser object in my dialog which will have HTML written to it. It is in a vertical layout with several other objects. I have the vertical size policy currently set to MinimumExpanding for this QTextbrowser. The problem is if the HTML written to the browser ends up taller than the QTextBrowser's minimum set height, its height stays the same and it instead makes me scroll down through the browser to see all the data, where I would like it instead to show all the data at once. I have tried changing around the size policies for the QTextBrowser and the layout it is in, but nothing I have tried has worked. Is there a way to do this that I am overlooking?

Comment: The idea of a QTextBrowser expanding as you fill it more seems odd to me, surely just make it bigger if you dont want the scroll, although scrolling does seem like a very normal expected behaviour if you surpass the size limitations of the text browser

Comment: Well does this want to be something that is done as you type or is it ok that after finishing typing the box will resize? because you could pretty easily set the height of the QTextbrowser after you know the number of lines that are going to be in it? in fact you could even do this as you go along line by line but that might look a bit off

Comment: @AngryDuck there isn't anything being typed into the box by the user, it is retrieving an html table from a webpage and displaying it, it only retrieves it once during the process so it would need to fit the height of that table once it's set as the browser's html

Comment: Ahhh right i see now, do you know how many lines you have got before you add them all? basically having a look i cant find any such function from QTextBrowser but if you know the number of lines you are going to add then you can determine a height for that many lines?

Comment: @AngryDuck I could most likely do that, since I have access to the html used beforehand. My project lead said he would like it done with just the QTextBrowser's properties instead of counting lines, but I've been scouring the web for a while now and I don't believe it can be done in that way, so that's probably the best way to go. Thanks :)

Comment: see answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how many lines you are going to add then you can work out a height and then set that height.

```
int number_of_lines; // If you can get this value from somewhere this should work

// Get the height of the font being used
QFontMetrics font_metrics(ui->text_browser->font());
int font_height = font_metrics.height();

// Get the height by multiplying number of lines by font height, Maybe add to this a bit for a slight margin?
int height = font_height * number_of_lines;

// Set the height to the text broswer
ui->text_browser->setMinimumHeight(height);
ui->text_browser->setMaximumHeight(height);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did help, unfortunately the space given to the browser is really big now -_- I figure I can just tinker with the numbers for a bit til a get it right though

Comment: hmm should work just check your number of lines etc is correct but no worries its how you set it anyway so like you said tinker a bit and should be fine

Comment: actually it turned out the new issue was from something else, this worked :)

Comment: Might want to use line spacing rather than font height.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#lineSpacing

Answer (score 3):

```
QTextBrowser  *m_text=new QTextBrowser;
m_text->setFixedHeight(m_text->document()->size().height());
```

wish to help you.